# Spark sbt scala build error - missing jars from ivy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to execute spark project from eclipse tool.
In build.sbt I have added below

```
name := "simple-spark-scala"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.6.2"
```

When I am importing this project I am getting error -

project is missing library around 100 such error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project 'simple-spark' is missing required library: '/root/.ivy2/cache/aopalliance/aopalliance/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar'    simple-spark        Build path  Build Path Problem
```

However I am able to see all the jars under the mentioned path in missing jar files

Any idea how to resolve ?

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency resolvers as below in your `built.sbt` file

```
resolvers += "MavenRepository" at "https://mvnrepository.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, you dont link `Spark Packages Repo`. You can see my `built.sbt` below:

```
name := "spark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-graphx_2.11" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.1.0",
  "neo4j-contrib" % "neo4j-spark-connector" % "2.0.0-M2"
)
```